# Samsung 700Z broken by Precise install

Tags: installation, hardware, boot-failure

I tried to install Precise from DVD media and got to the point where the Ubuntu logo is on screen indicating the the installer is loading.

At that point the screen went dark. After some time I rebooted the machine. To my dismay the machine would no longer start (Powers on but but no bios start up screen, I can hear initial hard drive spin which soon dies).

This is a new machine (less than 2 months) and I have had no previous indications of defects before this incident. In other words, I am convinced the Ubuntu install had something to do with the failure of the machine.

Has anyone else had this problem with this model machine? Is this known to happen with precise or other versions of Ubuntu?

Comment: Try fully removing all power sources(even the battery if one exists), holding the power button for a minute or two, reconnecting all power sources, and then trying to boot it up with the Precise installation disk *NOT* in the CD drive. If you cannot remove the disk, try yo use a BIOS key(usually F10, F12, or Esc) to select the hard disk as a boot device, then remove the CD.

Comment: It is possible (but unlikely) for any OS install to somehow leave your hard drive unbootable, but it does nothing to the BIOS.  My guess is that you have errors on the DVD.  It also sounds possible that Ubuntu actually booted from the DVD, with a display problem for some reason, and you are not doing a full reboot.  Following the directions by @ObsessiveFOSS should fix that, although powering off by holding down the power button for several seconds might also work if it's just going into standby instead of powering off.

Comment: Unfortunately on this model the battery is sealed inside the machine.

Comment: I cant get to the battery without voiding my warranty. What if I left the machine on until the battery dies? This might take quite some time since the machine is not doing anything at all.

Comment: Nope just seems completely broken. Thanks Ubuntu for breaking my machine.

Answer (score -2):

There is no solution to this problem for a Samsung 700Z. Basically don't install Ubuntu on this machine. If you do you risk the install hanging and leaving your machine in a broken state. You will have to open your machine to remove the DVD and battery (voiding you warranty) or sending it in for repair. IMHO Ubuntu should have a "install at your own risk" warning clearly posted somewhere on their site.

Comment: This answer is not really helpful to anybody. There are many people who **successfully** installed Ubuntu on a 700Z. Did you - by any chance - enable UEFI BIOS from a GPT partition you accidentally overwrote when installing Ubuntu?

Comment: @Takkat. OK, I don't care how many people successfully installed Ubuntu on a 700Z. There are probably many who ran into this problem as well. I suggest not installing Ubuntu on this machine as it may break the machine. It's the Ubuntu teams responsibility to find out whats wrong. I helped as much as I can. Also, if you had actually read the initial question you would know that what you are asking me about the problem is absolutely nonsense. Now I thank you for trying to help but you need to think before posting. BTW -- It may be more of a Kernel thing but it happened to me when install Ubuntu.